# How to link frontend and backend docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am currently developping a `Spring Boot` and a **reactJs application**, using Postgresql as a database. My Spring and my reactJs application are in a two seperate projects. I tried to dockerize my application using docker-compose. So in the server side I have both my postgresql and my `springboot` services defined in the docker-compose file.
Which is

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: app
    depends_on:
    - mypostgres
    ports:
     - "9000:8086"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=mypostgres
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=test
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432



  mypostgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    container_name: mypostgres

    ports:
     - "5433:5432"

    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
     - POSTGRES_USER=root
     - POSTGRES_DB=irooldb
    volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

For the `Client side`, I did not use docker-compose I only added a Dockerfile
and run my client side application in a seperate container.

My questions are:

How to link my client Container to my server side container?

Should I define a client service in the docker-compose file situated in the server side project? Or is it okay that they run sepratly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should I define a client service in the docker-compose file situated in the server side project?

This is one option, and this is probably the easiest and most straightforward. docker-compose, by default, sets up a docker network for the services you define per docker-compose.yml. Since all the services are on the same network then, they can resolve each other by hostname, i.e. your client application would reach backend like `http://app:9000/api/login/`, where you use the docker-compose service name as the host.

> Or is it okay that they run sepratly ?

It's ok to run them separately if you want. You *will* need to do a little modification to ensure the frontend can reach the backend. Two options would be:

1. **Create a docker bridge network manually**. [Here are the docs for that](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge). You'd just want to define a network with `docker network create`, [add that network in your docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network), and make sure you put your frontend container in the same network when you `docker run` it by using the `--network` option. Similarly, you can just define a new network in your docker-compose.yml, skip creating it by hand, and put your frontend container in that network.

Any of these #1 options end up being brittle because you'd need to make sure your network is there before running the frontend, or possibly the docker-compose stack. Regardless, it's an option.

In bridge mode, which is the network mode default, referencing localhost in your container does not reference your host. For example, `curl localhost:9000` from your frontend will try to curl the frontend container on port 9000. `curl localhost:9000` from your app service should succeed, because it's curling itself.

2. **Use the host network driver**, [which will put your containers on your host network by removing the Docker network isolation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). Then everything would just use `localhost:<port>` to talk to each other.

If you don't have a good case for keeping the frontend out of the docker-compose.yml, I would encourage you to just add it there and be done. Doing that will offload a lot of the thinking to docker-compose. It will also scale better if you use a CI pipeline, and it will be easier to hand off to another developer because it's all in a neat package. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to have them running separately.

You need to connect them by placing both frontend and backend in same docker network (you don't need to put db in that network).

Just create manually a standalone network and then reference it in docker-compose as `external` - same for backend and frontend. Then you will be able to use the service names to make frontend talk to backend.

frontend-docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  frontend:
    networks:
      project_network:
networks:
  project_network:
    external: true
```

backend-docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    networks:
      project_network:
networks:
  project_network:
    external: true
```

`docker network create --attachable project_network`